# Delete statement hangs

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

This statement "hangs" the server:

`DELETE FROM StockPositions WHERE machineName LIKE 'P%';`

and

`DELETE FROM StockPositions WHERE machineName LIKE 'P%' LIMIT 1;`

***EDIT:*** *This actually DOES work! I will continue to test when it fails. I'm leaning towards some kind of locking issue anyway...*

The corresponding `SELECT`-statements work as expected (returning 500 rows).

This statement works fine:

`DELETE FROM StockPositions WHERE ID = 5226;`

- No foreign key cascade tables deletes. EDIT: Wrong! See my answer below.
- No triggers.
- No locks (appearantly).
- No ideas.

Any ideas what to look for?

*(No panic - I can solve this by workarounds but I'd really want to know what's going on!)*

***EDIT:***

```
CREATE TABLE `StockPositions` (
   `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `isEnabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `readableName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
   `machineName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
   `longName` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `accessibilityLevel` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `storey` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `lengthX` decimal(10,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `lengthY` decimal(10,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `lengthZ` decimal(10,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `positionType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `frequency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `module` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `prioritized` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `aisleID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `readableName` (`readableName`),
   UNIQUE KEY `machineName` (`machineName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11820 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: How many records does your table hold? How busy is your mysql server? How long does it hang? What is the structure of `StockPositions`? (the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE StockPositions`)

Comment: As @Jocelyn pointed, post the schema.

Comment: Rows: 8350
Busy: not at all - I did this on my own dev database (I did the test on my own after the live server produced the same error)
How long: more than my patience can bare. I aborted after 5 minutes.

Comment: are there any other process trying to insert or doing other tasks which might lock the table?

Comment: As I posted in my comment: It is on my own local development database - there "should" not be any inserts or other tasks locking the table... :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! * blushing *
The DELETE CASCADE is found in the *child*-table (not the parent).
Good to know. Thank you for you time and effort!